# Running an Ansible Playbook on a particular group of servers

Tags: ansible

I have the following /etc/ansible/hosts:

```
[ESNodes]
isk-vsrv643
isk-vsrv644
isk-vsrv645

[PerfSetup]
isk-dsrv613
isk-dsrv614
```

I know there is an option to run a playbook on particular hosts with -l
Is there a way to run a playbook only on the PerfSetup group?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Same way as you would do for hosts : `-l PerfSetup`

Comment: Will the engine gather facts about `ESNodes` as well? Suppose `PerfSetup` needs to know the IPs of those?

Comment: worth mentioning that this needs to be a subset of the `hosts` variable defined in your playbook YAML. In this case, you might need to set `all` in order to pick from a subset of any hosts in the file.

Comment: This is described in ansible-playbook's [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ansible-playbook) as:

`-l SUBSET, --limit=SUBSET Further limits the selected host/group patterns.`

Comment: how to limit group play is run on in playbook source code itself?

Comment: How to make `--list-tasks` show the host groups or hosts the `ansible-playbook` will apply to?