# How to run a Ansible playbook to a group of servers

Tags: deployment, ansible-2.x

I have a master playbook with a bunch of roles in it:

```
---
- hosts: target.machine.com
  roles:
    - role: software-install
      become: yes
      become_user: myself
      tags: sw_setup

    - role: another-softeware-install
      become: yes
      become_user: notmyself
      tags: another_installation

In my hosts file for Ansible, I have 

[myservers]
server-one.com
server-two.com
```

I would like to run software-install role on group of servers under [my-servers] group. Sorry I am new to this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

I also tried to run the following

```
ansible-playbook -s masterPlaybook.yml -K -l myservers --tags another_installation
```

but it gives an error stating that invalid host pattern [server-one].

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I was going in the right direction. It is `-l myservers` that is correct. When it said that it was an invalid host pattern it was because that I need to add the hosts under `myservers` to `hosts` variable under my masterPlaybook.yml. This link helped [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129422/running-an-ansible-playbook-on-a-particular-group-of-servers).